# How to run laravel dusk in headfull mode from Sail and see the browser running the tests

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-dusk, laravel-sail

I am playing around with Laravel sail and dusk for BDD.
I have exactly followed [Laravel sail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#laravel-dusk) and I was able to run the tests in headless or headfull mode inside the sail container. But I want to see the test running by opening the browser. It would be easy if I was not using sail. Since I am using it, I am being unable to do so.
Any instruction to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can run the selenium standalone on your Windows Machine with Java installed.

1. Download the Selenium v4 [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) into local dir (e.g. `D:\Selenium`)
2. Download the Chrome Driver [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) into local dir (e.g. `D:\Selenium`)
3. Add the local dir (e.g. `D:\Selenium`) in to PATH
4. Open `cmd` and execute (replace your filename and your local host IP)

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.1.1.jar standalone --host 192.168.1.180
```

5. In your `.env.dusk.local`,

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
DUSK_HEADLESS_DISABLED=true
DUSK_DRIVER_URL=http://192.168.1.180:4444/wd/hub
```

so, you can run the Dusk with browser opening.